# Problem launching Intel Realsense D435 camera

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I’m trying to integrate an Intel RealSense D435 camera to try out some SLAM algorithms.I encountered an error mentioned [here](https://github.com/IntelRealSense/librealsense/issues/1131) .  As suggested i tried to apply the fix provided [here](https://github.com/icarpis/realsense/commit/292e7f8204aa1ab03633a0b161e47ccdbdb69bc4#diff-916dec94839aa2851dff65f548e1cbb2). I did this however in the original `realsense_node_factory.h` file while retaining a copy of the original file.When this previous solution didn’t work for me i deleted the original and tried to use the copy of the `realsense_node_factory.h` file that i had saved earlier.When i tried to run the demo_pointcloud.launch i get errors as shown below.

```
SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/accel_fps: 1000
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/accel_optical_frame_id: _accel_optical_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/align_depth: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_color_frame_id: _aligned_depth_to...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_fisheye_frame_id: _aligned_depth_to...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_infra1_frame_id: _aligned_depth_to...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/aligned_depth_to_infra2_frame_id: _aligned_depth_to...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/base_frame_id: _link
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_frame_id: _color_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_optical_frame_id: _color_optical_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/color_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_frame_id: _depth_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_optical_frame_id: _depth_optical_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/depth_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_color: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_depth: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_fisheye: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_imu: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_infra1: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_infra2: False
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_pointcloud: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/enable_sync: True
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/filters: 
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_optical_frame_id: _fisheye_optical_...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/fisheye_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/gyro_fps: 1000
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/gyro_optical_frame_id: _gyro_optical_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_frame_id: _infra1_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_optical_frame_id: _infra1_optical_f...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra1_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_fps: 30
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_frame_id: _infra2_frame
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_height: 480
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_optical_frame_id: _infra2_optical_f...
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/infra2_width: 640
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/json_file_path: 
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pointcloud_texture_index: 0
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/pointcloud_texture_stream: RS2_STREAM_COLOR
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/rosbag_filename: 
 * /camera/realsense2_camera/serial_no: 
 * /rosdistro: kinetic
 * /rosversion: 1.12.14

NODES
  /camera/
    realsense2_camera (nodelet/nodelet)
    realsense2_camera_manager (nodelet/nodelet)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[camera/realsense2_camera_manager-1]: started with pid [9284]
process[camera/realsense2_camera-2]: started with pid [9285]
process[camera/rviz-3]: started with pid [9286]
[ INFO] [1540453591.454769764]: Initializing nodelet with 8 worker threads.
[ERROR] [1540453591.480682615]: Failed to load nodelet [/camera/realsense2_camera] of type [realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory] even after refreshing the cache: Could not find library corresponding to plugin realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[ERROR] [1540453591.480716534]: The error before refreshing the cache was: Could not find library corresponding to plugin realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory. Make sure the plugin description XML file has the correct name of the library and that the library actually exists.
[FATAL] [1540453591.480830516]: Failed to load nodelet '/camera/realsense2_camera` of type `realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory` to manager `realsense2_camera_manager'
[camera/realsense2_camera-2] process has died [pid 9285, exit code 255, cmd /opt/ros/kinetic/lib/nodelet/nodelet load realsense2_camera/RealSenseNodeFactory realsense2_camera_manager __name:=realsense2_camera __log:=/home/ubuntu/.ros/log/1ca0353a-d820-11e8-8449-001b1bf788da/camera-realsense2_camera-2.log].
log file: /home/ubuntu/.ros/log/1ca0353a-d820-11e8-8449-001b1bf788da/camera-realsense2_camera-2*.log
```

When i try to run `catkin_make` on my workspace i get another error.

```
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target std_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target sensor_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_IMUInfo
[  0%] Built target _realsense2_camera_generate_messages_check_deps_Extrinsics
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_gencfg
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target dynamic_reconfigure_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target _catkin_empty_exported_target
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[  0%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[  0%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[  0%] Built target bond_generate_messages_py
[  0%] Built target tf_generate_messages_cpp
[  0%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target realsense2_camera_gencfg
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target geometry_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 18%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target bond_generate_messages_cpp
[ 18%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_lisp
[ 18%] Built target bond_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target bond_generate_messages_lisp
[ 18%] Built target tf2_msgs_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target nodelet_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target bond_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target diagnostic_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 18%] Built target rosgraph_msgs_generate_messages_py
[ 18%] Built target tf_generate_messages_lisp
[ 18%] Built target roscpp_generate_messages_py
[ 18%] Built target tf_generate_messages_py
[ 18%] Built target tf_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_cpp
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_eus
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_lisp
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 18%] Built target actionlib_msgs_generate_messages_cpp
[ 27%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_lisp
[ 40%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_py
[ 54%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_eus
[ 63%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_cpp
[ 72%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages_nodejs
[ 72%] Built target realsense2_camera_generate_messages
make[2]: *** No rule to make target '/home/ubuntu/catkin_ws/src/realsense-2.1.0/realsense2_camera/src/realsense_node_factory.cpp', needed by 'realsense-2.1.0/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/realsense_node_factory.cpp.o'.  Stop.
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1188: recipe for target 'realsense-2.1.0/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [realsense-2.1.0/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j8 -l8" failed
```

I searched for this file `'realsense-2.1.0/realsense2_camera/CMakeFiles/realsense2_camera.dir/src/realsense_node_factory.cpp.o'` and it doesn’t exist anymore,which i think is the problem. How do i fix this ?I’m unclear how to fix my original problem of implementing a hardware reset if i can not even make the proposed changes for a solution. Any advice would be very helpful..

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/308293/problem-launching-intel-realsense-d435-camera/) by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 166 on 2018-11-13

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The `realsense_node_factory.cpp.o` file is an intermediate object file created by the compiler before it is linked into a binary file. It is a generated file so you won't find it in any of the repositories.

Have you tried cloning the whole [resetdev branch](https://github.com/icarpis/realsense/tree/reset_dev) of the repository here instead of just patching a single file?

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [curi_ROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/37504/curi_ros/) on 2018-11-13**:
This worked for me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
Maybe you did an upgrade with "sudo apt-get upgrade"?

if you did so you need to clone the latest version of the realsense pkg.
I have this camera also. I am using with the "realsense2" pkg.

---

Originally posted by [Aviad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34139/aviad/) with karma: 96 on 2018-11-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1